# how to solve error possibly 'null' for typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

hey guys i try to make handlesave and handle clik like below but i am new to typescript and get error for cropRef.current

error:

> 'cropRef.current' is possibly 'null'.

here the code handle save

```
 const handleSave = async () => {
    if (cropRef) {
      const dataUrl = cropRef.current.getImage().toDataURL();
      const result = await fetch(dataUrl);
      const blob = await result.blob();
      setPreview(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
      setModalOpen(false);
    }
  };
```

error:

> 'inputRef.current' is possibly 'null'.

code handle click

```
const handleInputClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    inputRef.current.click();
  };
```

do you guys know how to solve this kind of error ? please tell me in detail because i am still learning about typescript its new to me

Comment: `if (cropRef && cropRef.current !== null) {`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `useRef` hook in React, for example to get a handle on an HTML element that you can render, it's common practice to give the ref a default value of `null`.

This default value will be the ref's value until it's set to something else. For example, if it's being set to an HTML element via a `ref` prop then it will remain `null` during the component's initial render pass, when it hasn't yet been inserted into the DOM, (and it would also be `null` if the ref is on an element that isn't always rendered).

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
    const rootRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    console.log(rootRef.current); // <- `null` the first time, then a `HTMLDivElement`

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(rootRef.current); // <- Always a `HTMLDivElement`, because `useEffect` runs after rendering
    }, [])

    return <div ref={rootRef}></div>;
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSG2RSyZcAvnGVBCHAORSoacDcAKEFl8AOwzAIYuAFkAngGF2kMUjEwAFAEpcguAbhppheGwgx6cALwFi9ADwAJACqyAMgBFgANxIAbJBB1GAA+TTF8f39tIX1DYzFCCECAOn8IAHNNc0skMlS0fCgeDVi4AHoKuAcAWjgAA0johrgYAAskFmAoUzbQJGwO9TgURtcPbz9A4I0G4UM7UgoqLR0bUL1FxcTktIzs3PpC4tKYcqqa+oBBfwB3FHlCUfG3L18AoJCG7AAjKhQtEatHIlAwrSg4meKDIMCQUDgpQAJvDgGJMvEDIxsABtAC62gWhh4MGKMgcSN8iPy1hwR3yjFCDgqlJ8oSEjEEQA)

If you use `createRef` and you don't pass a default value, `null` will be used by default as well. It's not clear from your question exactly how your ref is created.

---

The easiest way to deal with this is just to check that `cropRef.current !== null`, so you'll never try to access properties on it while it is `null`. Depending on what possible values might be stored in your ref, sometimes just a check for truthiness might be enough, i.e. `if (cropRef.current) { // ...`

Sometimes, you may find it convenient to just use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to access a property via `?.` only if your ref's current value is not `null` or `undefined`, e.g. `cropRef.current?.getImage().toDataURL()`